# 3des in ios providing different encrypted value each time on load?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, des

can any one suggest me why 3des in ios results different encoded string each time onload in ios? initially i am converting "key" into md5 formatted string and then used the same as a key in 3des to generate the encoded value.

here is my code:

```
-(NSData *)tripleDesEncryptString:(NSString *)input key:(NSString* )key error:(NSError **)error{
    //TDES
    NSParameterAssert(input);
    NSParameterAssert(key);
    NSData *inputData = [input dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *keyData = [key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    size_t outLength;
    //NSAssert(keyData.length == kCCKeySize3DES, @"the keyData is an invalid size");
    NSMutableData *outputData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:(inputData.length  +  kCCBlockSize3DES)];
    CCCryptorStatus result = CCCrypt(
        kCCEncrypt, // operation
        kCCAlgorithm3DES, // Algorithm
        kCCOptionECBMode | kCCOptionPKCS7Padding, // options
        keyData.bytes, // key
        keyData.length, // keylength
        nil, // iv
        inputData.bytes, // dataIn
        inputData.length, // dataInLength,
        outputData.mutableBytes, // dataOut
        outputData.length, // dataOutAvailable
        &outLength // dataOutMoved
    );

    if (result != kCCSuccess) {
        if (error != NULL) {
            *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"com.your_domain.your_project_name.your_class_name." code:result userInfo:nil];
        }
        return nil;
    }
    [outputData setLength:outLength];
    return outputData;
}

-(void) testEncryptionAndDecryption {
    NSString *str =@"ker!@#$%^&*()";
    id md5data =[str MD5];
    NSString *md5dataString =(NSString *)md5data;
    NSData *encrypted = [self tripleDesEncryptString:@"abcdef@dd.com:123" key:md5dataString error:nil];
    NSString *strData = [encrypted  base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
    NSLog(@"encrypted data length: %@",strData);
    NSString *str2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:encrypted encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",str2);
}
```

Comment: 1. The simple answer is because the input parameters are not the same, check that the parameters are the exact correct length. 2. Do not use 3DES for new work, it is not secure, use AES. Do not ECB mode, it is not secure.

Comment: **Never use [ECB mode](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14487/13022)**. It's deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. You should at the very least use a randomized mode like [CBC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22260/13022) or [CTR](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2378/13022). It is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme.

Comment: Actually **Never** is a little bit strong. If you are encryption data that is exactly one block in length (no padding) and the key is unique and randomly generated adding a IV and CBC mode accomplished nothing. There are currently instances where this is done in compliance with current standards.

Comment: Interestingly Apple removed the padding error code from Common Crypto several years ago so a padding oracle will not occur by accident. Other libraries should remove the error code as well.

Answer (score 2):

The test code is flawed.

```
NSString *str =@"ker!@#$%^&*()";
id md5data =[str MD5];
NSString *md5dataString =(NSString *)md5data;
```

It is unclear what `MD5` is, probably a category?

The `MD5` function produces a 16-byte result but 3DES requires a 24-byte key.

`NSString *str2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:encrypted encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`  will fail because arbitrary data can bot be represented as a string. That is why Base64 is used.

It really is best to write an encryption method that takes and returns `NSData` arguments and a do any string operation outside of it. That creates single responsibility methods.

Here is a refactored version--but still insecure:

```
-(NSData *)tripleDesEncryptData:(NSData *)data
                            key:(NSData* )key
                          error:(NSError **)error {
    NSParameterAssert(data);
    NSParameterAssert(key);
    NSAssert(key.length == kCCKeySize3DES, @"the keyData is an invalid size");

    size_t outLength;
    NSMutableData *outputData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:(data.length  +  kCCBlockSize3DES)];

    CCCryptorStatus
    result = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, // operation
                     kCCAlgorithm3DES, // Algorithm
                     kCCOptionECBMode | kCCOptionPKCS7Padding , // options
                     key.bytes, // key
                     key.length, // keylength
                     nil,// iv
                     data.bytes, // dataIn
                     data.length, // dataInLength,
                     outputData.mutableBytes, // dataOut
                     outputData.length, // dataOutAvailable
                     &outLength); // dataOutMoved

    if (result != kCCSuccess) {
        if (error != NULL) {
            *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"com.your_domain.your_project_name.your_class_name."
                                         code:result
                                     userInfo:nil];
        }
        return nil;
    }
    [outputData setLength:outLength];
    return outputData;
}

- (NSData *)hash192String:(NSString *)inputString {
    NSData *inputData = [inputString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSMutableData *hash = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CC_SHA256(inputData.bytes, (unsigned int)inputData.length, hash.mutableBytes);

    return [hash subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 24)];
}


-(void) testEncryptionAndDecryption {
    NSString *md5String  = @"ker!@#$%^&*()";
    NSString *stringData = @"abcdef@dd.com:123";

    NSData *keyData   = [self hash192String:md5String];
    NSData *data      = [stringData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *encrypted = [self tripleDesEncryptData:data key:keyData error:nil];

    NSString *encryptedBase64 = [encrypted  base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

    NSLog(@"encrypted base64\nlength: %lu\nstring: %@", (unsigned long)encryptedBase64.length, encryptedBase64);
}
```

Output:

> encrypted base64
>   length: 32
>   string: +VSdzF4BmAMnGITAWFqaY2mgp8Nr8I13

Comment: yes it is category.from md5 i can able to get 32byte key.is it 3DES needs exactly 24byte key?

Comment: Yes, 3DES needs a 24-byte key, The way you are generation the key may be using whatever data follows `md5data`.  Also the cast: `NSString *md5dataString =(NSString *)md5data;` is suspicious.

Comment: i tried directly with string NSString *md5data =[str MD5]; but no change

Comment: For a test I used: `NSString *md5dataString = @"123456781234567812345678";` and get the same results each time.

Comment: When you have problems you need to debug. That can include adding `NSLog` statements to inspect the actual data. cryptography is byte based so the best way to see the data is with hex dumps. IF you dump the key,  input and output data you will see the problem: different days and/or incorrect data lengths.

Comment: keyData.length i changed to  kCCKeySize3DES. now it's showing same result each time.but unable to match the result. i added NSString *partString = [md5dataString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 24)]; to restrict key to 24 bytes. am i doing in right way?

Comment: Look at the answer, MD5 returns 16-bytes so you can't subrange to 24-bytes there aren't enough bytes.

Comment: You can use SHA256 and subrange to 24-bytes.

Comment: oh fine then am using this   NSString *md5dataString =[str MD5];
   NSString *partString = [md5dataString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 16)];
    NSString  *finalKey =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",md5dataString,partString];

Answer (score 0):

```
func testCrypt(data:NSData, keyData:NSData, ivData:NSData) -> String {

    var base64cryptString = String()
    let cryptData    = NSMutableData(length: Int(data.length) + kCCBlockSizeAES128)!
    let keyLength              = size_t(kCCKeySizeAES128)
    let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCEncrypt)
    let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithmAES128)
    let options:   CCOptions   = UInt32(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)

    var numBytesEncrypted :size_t = 0
    let cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
                              algoritm,
                              options,
                              keyData.bytes, keyLength,
                              ivData.bytes,
                              data.bytes, data.length,
                              cryptData.mutableBytes, cryptData.length,
                              &numBytesEncrypted)

    if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
        cryptData.length = Int(numBytesEncrypted)
        base64cryptString = cryptData.base64EncodedString(options: .endLineWithLineFeed)
    }
    return base64cryptString
}
```

You can call `func testCrypt(data:NSData, keyData:NSData, ivData:NSData)` by passing the data which needs to be encrypted and the key and value in NSData format.

For example:

```
let data: NSData! = message.data(using: .utf8) as NSData!; 
let keyData: NSData! = keyValue.data(using: .utf8) as NSData!; 
let ivData: NSData! = ivValue.data(using: .utf8) as NSData!;
var base64cryptString = self.testCrypt(data: data, keyData: keyData, ivData: ivData)
```

Comment: could you provide some more information about this solution?

Comment: you can call
func testCrypt(data:NSData, keyData:NSData, ivData:NSData) by passing the data which need to encrypted , key and value in NSData format. Ex:                                                                                                
            let data: NSData! =  message.data(using: .utf8) as NSData!;
            let keyData: NSData! = keyValue.data(using: .utf8) as NSData!;
            let ivData: NSData! = ivValue.data(using: .utf8) as NSData!;
            var base64cryptString = self.testCrypt(data: data, keyData: keyData, ivData: ivData)